# Don't show footcite notes

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, footnotes

I am using a `biblatex-examples.bib` file with website cites.

I would like to hide the (Online; visited on 15-11-2014) part of the footnote, but do show this part in the Bibliography. Is this possible?

A minimal example with the settings and packages I use

```
\documentclass[a4paper,dutch]{report}
% times is deprecated - don't use it
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage[scaled=.90]{helvet}
\usepackage{courier}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,citestyle=verbose-ibid,bibstyle=numeric,sorting=nyt]{biblatex}
\renewcommand{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\addspace}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
    @misc{guardian1,
  author = {The Guardian},
  title = {{Cyprus banks remain closed to prevent run on deposits}},
  howpublished = "\url{http://www.theguardian.com/world/2013/mar/26/cyprus-banks-closed-prevent-run-deposits}",
  note = "(Online; visited on 15-11-2014)"
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

% %First some renames to dutch
\renewcommand\bibname{Literatuurlijst}
% \renewcommand\contentsname{Inhoudsopgave}

\chapter{Title}
Text and footcite\footcite[][]{guardian1}


\cleardoublepage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Literatuurlijst}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

This example is coming from
[Bibliography and footcites](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/212601/bibliography-and-footcites)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{..}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: @Guido I added this example, with the packages I use included.

Comment: You need to provide the relevant bib entries or modify your MWE to use things included in e.g. `biblatex-examples.bib`. We need to be able to copy-paste-compile your code to reproduce the issue and try out solutions.

Comment: Note that `times` is deprecated and ought not be used.

Comment: @cfr I edited the example, bib file has biblatex-examples.bib as name now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can prevent notes to be printed in (full) citations by "clearing" the content of the how the `note` at every citation. This can be done with the `\AtEveryCitekey` hook (the bibliographic data is available at `\AtEveryCitekey` but not at `\AtEveryCite`)

```
\AtEveryCitekey{\clearfield{note}}
```

Given the example, a better solution would be to use the `url` and `urldate` fields, i.e.,

```
@misc{guardian2,
  author = {The Guardian},
  title = {Cyprus banks remain closed to prevent run on deposits},
  url = "http://www.theguardian.com/world/2013/mar/26/cyprus-banks-closed-prevent-run-deposits",
  urldate = "2014-11-15"
}
```

and then, to remove the access date from full citations, we can use the `xpatch` package (i.e., `\usepackage{xpatch}`) to patch the appropriate bibmacro.

```
\xpatchbibmacro{url+urldate}
  {\usebibmacro{urldate}}
  {\ifcitation{}{\usebibmacro{urldate}}}
  {}
  {}
```

The output produced by the two approached is the following:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I inserted the first bit of code right after the    \begin{document} and the second bit of code after the    \cleardoublepage in my example. Unfortunately this gives me an arror: Undefined control sequence. \xpatchbibmacro       {url+urldate}.

Comment: You have to load the `xpatch` package, i.e., `\usepackage{xpatch}`

Comment: I did added the xpatch package now, but still no changes visible. Did I included the code on the right places? I still use     \footcite[][]{guardian2} for the notes, is that right?

Comment: The code should be placed before the occurrences of `\footcite`. I would put them in the preamble (before `\begin{document}`).

Comment: I did put both codes right above the \begin{document}, still no changes. Which code did you used to test it?

Comment: I have used the code in the MWE for the `\DeclareFieldFormat` solution. For the second solution I have the same code but I have changed the bib entry as in my  answer. Did you rerun `bibtex`?

Comment: I did used both codes, now I see there are 2 solutions in your answer. The first solution works, but ends the note with an comma, I would like no comma or a point.
The second solution doesn't work. I did added the third code block of your answer before \begin{document} and changed the bibentry. I still get the (visited on XX) part in the footnote.

Comment: I overlooked the comma. Changed the first option. For the second option, do you still have the note  in the bib entry?

Comment: The first option is working great now, but the second one seems more useful. I recopied my MWE, changed the @misc entry to the entry you gave. Then I added the \usepackage{xpatch} and the \xpatchbibmacro block right above the \begin{document}. After rerunning BibTex, I still get the footcite with the (bezocht op 15-11-2014) note.

Comment: Which version of biblatex are you using? The solution has been tested on biblatex 2.9a (the screenshot has been created by that run).

Comment: I was using 2.8a, after updating I got the second version working too. Thanks soo much for your efford.