# Bibliography and footcites

Tags: bibliographies

I would like to change the point in a comma (but keep the last one) in the bibliography and footcites with misc. I think it is a language problem, but can't find the problem. Is this changeable?

Current:

```
The Guardian. Cyprus banks remain closed to prevent run on deposits. http://www.theguardian.com/world/2013/mar/26/cyprus-banksclosed-prevent-run-deposits. (Online; visited on 15-11-2014).
```

I would like:

```
The Guardian, (comma) Cyprus banks remain closed to prevent run on deposits, (comma) http://www.theguardian.com/world/2013/mar/26/cyprus-banksclosed-prevent-run-deposits, (comma) (Online; visited on 15-11-2014).
```

biblatex-examples.bib file:

```
@misc{guardian1,
  author = {The Guardian},
  title = {{Cyprus banks remain closed to prevent run on deposits}},
  howpublished = "\url{http://www.theguardian.com/world/2013/mar/26/cyprus-banks-closed-prevent-run-deposits}",
  note = "(Online; visited on 15-11-2014)"
}
```

biblatex-examples.tex:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage[dutch]{babel}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,citestyle=verbose-ibid,bibstyle=numeric,sorting=nyt]{biblatex}

\usepackage{graphicx, url, wrapfig} %pictures

\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref} %Makes Table of Contents clickable
\usepackage{eurosym} %symbool eurosign

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}

%First some renames to dutch
\renewcommand{\chaptername}{Hoofdstuk}
\renewcommand\bibname{Literatuurlijst}
\renewcommand\contentsname{Inhoudsopgave}

\includecomment{comment} %change exclude to include for showing in pdf too

\chapter{Title}
Text and footcite\footcite[][]{guardian1} 


\cleardoublepage
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Literatuurlijst}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just want to change the unit punctuation? I've reduced your code a bit to remove things not really relevant to your question. (Unless you wanted to include pictures of commas ;).)

```
\documentclass[a4paper,dutch]{report}
% times is deprecated - don't use it
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage[scaled=.90]{helvet}
\usepackage{courier}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,citestyle=verbose-ibid,bibstyle=numeric,sorting=nyt]{biblatex}
\renewcommand{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\addspace}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
    @misc{guardian1,
  author = {The Guardian},
  title = {{Cyprus banks remain closed to prevent run on deposits}},
  howpublished = "\url{http://www.theguardian.com/world/2013/mar/26/cyprus-banks-closed-prevent-run-deposits}",
  note = "(Online; visited on 15-11-2014)"
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

% %First some renames to dutch
\renewcommand\bibname{Literatuurlijst}
% \renewcommand\contentsname{Inhoudsopgave}

\chapter{Title}
Text and footcite\footcite[][]{guardian1}


\cleardoublepage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Literatuurlijst}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image: commas]

Comment: The unit puctuation did the trick. Thanks a lot for this. I am trying to understand your other changes too. But I see no difference in my file when I add or remove the courier and csquotes package. What does this package?
May I copy your code to use in my other open question? This is a more clear code I see.

Comment: @RemcoSwienink The `courier` bit won't make a difference unless you use sans serif. It is part of the recommended replacement for loading `times`. (The 3 lines set the serif, sans serif and typewriter fonts for text and the fonts for maths.) `csquotes` is recommended with `biblatex`. It can help with various aspects of punctuation, especially quotation marks, and is sensitive to e.g. the fact you are using `dutch` settings for the document. You can read the manual for more details. You can drop it if you really don't want it. `xparse` is also recommended for `biblatex`.

Comment: @RemcoSwienink If this answered your question, please consider accepting it by clicking on the greyed-out tick at the top left of the answer. This helps people searching see that your question includes a solution. Disclaimer: it will also give me 'points'. But you will get some, too ;).

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. May I use your Minimal Example at another question?

Comment: @RemcoSwienink Yes. You should link to this question, though, so people can see the background and the code is attributed. (All code posted here is licensed according to a CC licence with attribution, I think. So you don't need me to say it is OK. But it is OK anyway!)

Comment: Happy to learn all of this. I updated my other question with your code (http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/212452/dont-show-footcite-notes).